# Do I need to deal with Timezone and Daylight Saving conversions for an international hairdressing web app calendar?

Tags: c#, angular, calendar, timezone

I have to create a reservation calendar that can be used by different hairdressers in different countries.

In my case, the user browser could be in any localization/timezone, my server is in EST and my SQL is also located in a different timezone. My app is basically in Angular 6 + Netcore 3.0 and SQL DB.

In my calendar, you can create an event adding 30 minutes, so you can book for example from 2 pm to 4:30 pm, 5 pm or 5:30 pm ..and so on.
Each calendar is associated with a physical hairdressing place, Could it be better to work with Date(year, month, day), and hours and minutes separately and avoid time conversions?

If there is hairdressing in Madrid, for every part of the world I have to show the same calendar. If the hairdressing opens at 9 am in Madrid, I have to show it to any user in the world at 9 am (Madrid time).

Also, Daylight Saving is meaningless because every event will be fixed in date + hour + minutes...

Comment: Will you need to show the "current" appointment, send an email reminder before the appointment, or do *anything* that relates the appointment to "now"?  You won't need time zones for the scheduling piece (those should be in the location's local time, as Ziga said), but you should store a time zone identifier with each location so you can do those "now" operations.

Comment: I would. Even if  you assume that a summer time transition (DST crossover) never happens during opening hours and the customers are always in the same time zone as the hairdresser, it’s good to be prepared for the unlikely. Already in the moment when you want to send an iCal event to the customer’s calendar, you need to know the time zone, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would save the timezone of the hairdressing company and then save all of the times as without the timezone and then convert it back on frontend, where you know the timezone of the user (in javascript).

So: the users selects 5:30PM in Madrid. You save just the date so 2020-05-15 17:30 and then on frontend you just display that and next  to it (Madrid Time)